# How can I compare two files and write out the differeneces?

Tags: python

here is a script I found which takes two files to compare:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).intersection(file2)

same.discard('\n')

with open('data.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
```

but this one writes out to the data the lines which are the and I would like to write out the differences.

Comment: Use `difference` instead of `intersection`.

Comment: All the set operations are listed [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects)

Comment: @Barmar: or `difference = set(file) - set(file2)`

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html).

> This module provides classes and functions for comparing sequences. It
>   can be used for example, for comparing files, and can produce
>   difference information in various formats, including HTML and context
>   and unified diffs. For comparing directories and files, see also, the
>   filecmp module.